# Publish CSV to Enterprise Portal as table

Tags: arcgis-pro, csv, arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api

I'm following this help doc.
https://geosaurus.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a1db6db172bc49a8932daacc2ed3d3ac#preview

I'm able to add the CSV to the Portal, but I cannot get it to publish. I need it published as a table. It doesn't have coordinate fields and it's not intended to be a spatial feature.

```
from IPython.display import display
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import os
gis = GIS('Home')

csv_file = r'C:\Users\jpilbeam\Downloads\c19_Vaccine_Current.csv'
csv_item = gis.content.add({}, csv_file)#add csv to Portal

csv_layer = csv_item.publish(None, file_type='csv')


Error:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [15]:
Line 1:     csv_layer = csv_item.publish(None, file_type='csv')

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py, in publish:
Line 10353: elif not buildInitialCache and ret[0]['type'].lower() == 'image service':

KeyError: 'type'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Other attempts:

```
csv_layer = csv_item.publish()
KeyError: 'type'
```

```
csv_layer = csv_item.publish('csv')
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

```
csv_layer = csv_item.publish(publishParameters={"type":"csv"})
TypeError: publish() got an unexpected keyword argument 'publishParameters'
```

I also tried what the help doc does. It has a text field with place name values specified in the `address_fields` parameter. My CountyName field is also a text field with place names. But, this also errors.

```
csv_flayer = csv_item.publish(None, {"Address":"CountyName"})
KeyError: 'type'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it has something to do with the encoding of the CSV file. I was able to publish the CSV after completing the following steps.

1. Open the CSV in a text editor (I used Notepad).
2. Save it. Use a .csv file extension type --> Save as type: All Files --> Encoding: utf-8
   [image]
3. try publishing to Enterprise Portal with this:

```
from IPython.display import display
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import os
gis = GIS('Home') #uses current Notebook as workspace

csv_file = r'C:\pathto\your.csv' #path to CSV
csv_item = gis.content.add({}, csv_file) #add CSV to Enterprise Portal
display(csv_item) #display it here 

#location parameter needs to be set to "none" when publishing to Enterprise Portal
params={"type":"csv","locationType":"none"} 
csv_item.publish(publish_parameters=params) #publish to Enterprise Portal
```

This is not the fastest workflow. If you're able to set the encoding to utf-8 back when you originally create your CSV then that would be better.